# mix static and dynamic cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have dynamic cells in tableView, but in top of dynamic cells i want add a static cell that contain two label.
i searched but i did not find my solution.
what should i do?
(i am begginer)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return dictionary.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : TicketDetailTableViewCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TicketDetailTableViewCell

        var dict = dictionary[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblComment.text = dict["comment"] as? String
        cell.lblDate.text = dict["date"] as? String

        return cell


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "static cell"? Do you want the first row in the table to be different than the rest of the rows? Do you want a Header on the table?

Comment: Do you really have an array named "dictionary"?

Comment: @DonMag. yes exactly.

Comment: Yes!  Naming is important.  If someone reads your code and their first reaction is to wonder why you're accessing a "dictionary" as if it were an array, you've just distracted them from understanding the real problem.

Comment: @PhillipMills. ok , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options...

1. Use a `.tableHeaderView` - you can use any normal `UIView` + subviews, labels, images, etc, etc, etc
2. Create a second prototype cell, and use that cell as your "first row". You can lay it out in Storyboard however you want... just because it is a prototyped cell, doesn't mean you have to change anything when you use it.

Method 2 will end up looking similar to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // if it's the first row, show the prototype cell with
    // identifier "StaticCell"
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StaticCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell

    }

    // it's not the first row, so show the prototype cell with
    // identifier "cell"
    //
    // Note: you will need to "offset" the array index since the
    // "2nd row" is indexPath.row == 1
    let cell : TicketDetailTableViewCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TicketDetailTableViewCell

    var dict = dictionary[indexPath.row - 1]
    cell.lblComment.text = dict["comment"] as? String
    cell.lblDate.text = dict["date"] as? String

    return cell
}

// you will also need to return +1 on the number of rows
// so you can "add" the first, static row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dictionary.count + 1
}
```

Comment: i use your secend way. but it show nothing. what should i do??

Comment: @ali - did you create a second prototype cell?

Answer (score -1):

The main idea is that you implement `heightForRow` data source method where depending on the cell index path you will return either a static height or automatic height. Something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == staticCellIndex {
        return 80.0
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: please help me more, how can i add two label in that??

Comment: For adding labels to a UITableViewCell it's better that you do some tutorial first and then come with specific questions related to that.